# WSO2 API Manager TryIt feature null key

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I'm using the WSO2 API Manager and I've added an API to it that was created in the WSO2 ESB and when trying to use the TryIt feature I get the following error in the console log.

> [2014-09-16 13:59:26,614] ERROR - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure
>   org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /Sub, version: v1.0.0 with key: null
>       at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:157)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:92)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:285)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:83)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:64)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
>       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I'm trying to send a GET request and there are no parameters for this API and in the Authorization field I have entered

```
Bearer XXXACCESS+TOKEN+GOES+HEREXXXX
```

When testing this from Advanced REST client or the REST Client in the store it works. I've changed the port numbers in the various files (authorize, login, token, revoke) to match my port offset, I've also configured my API Store addresses in api-manager.xml.

Comment: On the TryIt page, were you adding the header as 'Raw' or 'Form'?

Comment: what is the version that your using?

Comment: Dakshika I'm using version 1.7.0 and Colinr I think its Form

Comment: When using Advanced REST client it works on both Raw and Form

Answer (score 1):

When you add that particular resource to your API, please select "OPTIONS" verb as well. Otherwise this error would be given.

[image]

Also, check whether your /etc/hosts entries direct 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' instead of the IP address of your machine. In that case, please open

```
    {API-M installation DIR}/repository/conf/api-manager.xml
```

And, modify the section relevant to the Swagger appropriately by adding your IP address (or host-name)

from this,

```
    <!--Configuration to enable/disable sending CORS headers from the Gateway-->
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>

    <!--The value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Default values are 
        API Store addresses, which is needed for swagger to function.-->
    <Access-Control-Allow-Origin>https://localhost:9443,http://localhost:9763</Access-Control-Allow-Origin>

    <!--Configure Access-Control-Allow-Headers-->
    <Access-Control-Allow-Headers>authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type</Access-Control-Allow-Headers>

</CORSConfiguration>
```

to this (add your own server IP instead),

```
    <!--Configuration to enable/disable sending CORS headers from the Gateway-->
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>

    <!--The value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Default values are 
        API Store addresses, which is needed for swagger to function.-->
    <Access-Control-Allow-Origin>https://192.168.56.101:9443,http://192.168.56.101:9763</Access-Control-Allow-Origin>

    <!--Configure Access-Control-Allow-Headers-->
    <Access-Control-Allow-Headers>authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type</Access-Control-Allow-Headers>

</CORSConfiguration>
```

The above answer assumes that you didn't add any port offset to the API Manager. If you did, you should also change the port value(simply add that value to the existing port value) in the above configuration accordingly.

Thank you.

-Chathura

Comment: I've tried all of the above and it still does not work